# Should I `#ifdef DEBUG` guard debugging functions in .c files?

Tags: c, debugging, standards

Right now I have a debugging function, `printPassport`, in myfile.h file. It's declared as so:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void printPassport(passport_t *passport);
#endif
```

This seems to be the proper way to do things, though it's been a while since I've used C so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Should I put guards around the function name in myfile.c? i.e. should I do

```
void printPassport(passport_t *passport) {
...
}
```

or

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void printPassport(passport_t *passport) {
...
}
#endif
```

in myfile.c?

Comment: That's all very well and good, but what are you doing about the calls to the function? Typically, you need `#define printPassport(x)`, which converts to the calls to nothing when `DEBUG` is not defined.

Comment: I find that I like my debug functions (I often call them `dump_xyz()` for some significant value of `xyz`) to have a signature like: `void dump_xyz(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const xyz *ptr);` so that it can be used to write to `stderr`, `stdout` or some sort of log file, and the occurrence can be identified by the tag.  Sometimes I get lazy and omit the file stream argument, but production versions of the function usually have all three arguments.  It might sometimes be useful to add `const char *file, int line, const char *func` arguments, passing `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__func__` too.

Answer (score 3):

If you guard the function, then it won't be compiled when you don't define `DEBUG`, which means the code will get out of sync with the rest of the system.  Then, when you do need the debugging code, you first have to fix it before you can use it.

It is better in many respects to leave the function being compiled most of the time so that it is known to be valid.  Since you have the definition in a header, simply leave the function defined (and compiled) for normal builds.  You might use a conditional such as `#ifndef RELEASE_BUILD` to squeeze the unused function out of the final released product.  But the key is to ensure that the function is normally compiled, even if not normally used.  You also need to consider how the calls to the function are protected.  Is there a runtime debugging level to activate the debugging, or is it strictly a compile-time decision.  If it is decided at compile time, you will need suitable guards around the function calls, or a macroized call to the function that can be converted to `((void)0)` or something similar by the compiler.

If the function is static — local to one source file, then consider making it `static inline`.  This will be compiled, but will be ignored if it is never called without triggering complaints about unused `static` functions, even if there are no actual calls to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `NDEBUG` macro controls the `assert` macro; it may be useful to reuse it instead of having another macro.

Whether you want the function to exist, depends on the goal. If you don't need it, you can save compile time, and make the program more consistent by guarding it in .cpp and not having it.